# How to call a jQuery function in a jQuery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on extracting a callgraph of jQuery and experimenting on jQuery-1.9.1.js and I need to call some functions in jQuery in the same jQuery file. However, while I call the function it should be out of scope jQuery.

The reason, that I am doing this I want to see how deep does a function goes, when I call it.

By the term of "deep", I mention about the number of nodes that it passes until it reaches the leaf node of a callgraph.

Example of jQuery source code (jQuery 1.9.1) and what I am trying to do:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
.
.
.

})( window );

//Call a jQuery Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to call a function before it exists?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama no I call it right at the end of the scope of jQuery, so it is defined before I use it. The problem is I don't know how I can call it in jQuery's file.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but if you're curious about the way jQuery does things, it can help to look at the non-minified source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src

Comment: you should call the function inside the (function(... part.. or $(document).ready(function(){callFunc();})

Comment: @gulty it works only if I am in "(window)", but what if I want to call it out of window?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment:

To call a jQuery function simply do `$.Function(params...)`